# JQuery: detect selection of previously entered form data

Tags: jquery

The event

```
$('#myInput').live('keyup blur', function(event) {
    //...
}
```

is not triggered when I select a previously entered value that is offered to me by Firefox. (eg. form history).

Any ideas how to solve?

Comment: Do you focus out of the input box or press a key after selecting the previously entered value? Because those are the events it's listening for.

Comment: Try the change event. Does that fire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What JQuery version are you using? [This bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20780) appears to have been fixed.

Comment: sry, my bad. This was caused to weird Firefox caching issues. Should have known...I don't get it sometimes ctrl+F5 won't do it...

Comment: I think it's Shift+F5 on FF and Ctrl+F5 on Chrome

Comment: Better way is to use firebug and disable caching while developing.